# PyCharm cannot identify Interpreter after initial PyCharm download

Tags: python, ide, interpreter, pycharm

I am running Mac OSX 10.8.4 with Python 2.7 and I just downloaded PyCharm Version: 3.0 Build: 131.190.

When I opened it and chose "Create New Project", in the 'Interpreter' pull-down menu there was no options to chose an interpreter (It just says '').

Just in case it was an issue with Python (although I use IDLE regularly), I downloaded Python 3.3 just to see if the new version would be identified by PyCharm, but again with no luck - the 'Interpreter' pull down menu had no options to select (It just says '').

Im sure I am just overlooking something during installation, but why can't PyCharm identify the Interpreter?

Thanks!

Comment: did you try to click on configure interpeters and add a new one?

Comment: Yes, thats the first thing I did, haha. Both windows display "nothing to show".

Comment: strange sorry for asking something stupid but sometimes it happens. if you tried on 2.x version of pycharm it worths mentioning on your question. if not it worths trying. with more information you can get a faster answer.

Comment: I tried downloading PyCharm 2.7 with the same exact outcome.

Comment: Nevermind, figured it out :)

Comment: maybe you can post an answer it may help other people in the future!

Comment: Just check out this link http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/quickstart/configuring_interpreter.html regarding how to configure the Interpreters

Answer (score 2):

Its not supposed to. It did not for me. When I fist installed it, and created a new project, I just directed PyCharm to my Python installation.

You need to click one "New Project", then click on the "..." button next to the interpreter drop-down box, and then, you need to click on the `+` sign, choose to add "local", and then point to `python.exe` for whatever interpreter is installed.

Answer (score 0):

No worries, you can do this:

1. Open Preferences of pyCharm.
2. Click on Project:
3. Select the virtual env interpreter in drop down and apply & ok.
4. Go To edit configuration and select your interpreter there.

[image]